# get name from struct passed to function

Tags: go

How to get the name of an struct/interface?

## pkg

```
package crud

type User struct {
    ID          uint
    Name        string
    Email       string
}
```

## main

```
package main

import "./crud"

func get_struct(value interface{}){
    // print "User"
}

func main(){
    get_struct(&crud.User{})
}
```

Comment: Since you specifically mention "print", also be aware of [`fmt.Printf`'s "%T"](https://godoc.org/fmt#hdr-Printing) verb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`reflect`](https://godoc.org/reflect) package provides this; you simply create a new `reflect.Value` from the variable and inspect its type:

```
func get_struct(value interface{}){
    var name string
    ref := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if ref.IsValid() {
        name = ref.Type().Name()
    } else {
        name = "nil"
    }
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

Note: you may not get the output you want if a pointer is passed. You may want to consider using [`Type.String()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) over [`Type.Name()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type).

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Msg3ybZSaj)

Comment: I got another problem.. The `User{}` is from another package.. When using `reflect.Type()` return `*crud.User`..  `reflect.Type().Name()` is empty

Comment: @clarkk: you could [try something like this](https://play.golang.org/p/lwXrHM_HbB).

Comment: Thanks.. it works! but why the `for` loop in `get_struct`? :)

Comment: @clarkk:  In case you have a situation the type is `***crud.User`. The `for` loop will reduce it down to `User`.